# Calculating number of Messages in Folders in a parent-child relationship recursively using Java?

Tags: java, recursion, directory, tree

Each `Folder` has list of `Messages` and each `Folder` can have list of its children `Folders` and list of its own `Messages`. I'm struggling with recursion function which needs to return count of `Message` objects from any node `Folder` that is passed to that functions. Here are classes and some dummy date inserted to form a tree.

If I'm correct, this is not like Java's files and folders system. Here, `Message` cannot be `Folder`, so there is no Java's `isDirectory()`

```
    public class Folder {

        private Folder parent;
        private ArrayList<Message> mMessages;
        private ArrayList<Folder> children;

        public Folder(){
            this(null, new ArrayList<Folder>(), new ArrayList<Message>());
        }


        public Folder(Folder parent, ArrayList<Folder> children) {
            this.parent = parent;
            this.children = children;
        }

        public Folder(Folder parent, ArrayList<Folder> childrens, ArrayList<Message> messages ) {
            this.parent = parent;
            this.children = childrens;
            this.mMessages = messages;
        }
        public boolean hasChildren(){
            return this.getChildren().size() > 0;
        }

        public void addChildren(Folder child) {
            child.setParent(this);
            this.getChildren().add(child);
        }

        public void addMessage(Message message) {
            this.getMessages().add(message);
        }

        public boolean isRoot() {
            return parent == null;
        }
}
```

Here are dummy data:

```
Message m1 = new Message();
    Message m2 = new Message();
    Message m3 = new Message();


    //main root
    Folder root = new Folder();

    //root's folder children
    Folder level1a = new Folder();  level1a.addMessage(m1);
    Folder level1b = new Folder();  level1b.addMessage(m2);
    Folder level1c = new Folder();  level1c.addMessage(m3);

    //adding children to root
    root.addChildren(level1a); root.addChildren(level1b); root.addChildren(level1c);


    //adding children to level 1a
    Folder level1aa = new Folder(); 
    level1a.addChildren(level1aa);

    //adding messages to level 1aaa and 1aab
    Folder level1aaa = new Folder(); level1aaa.addMessage(new Message());
    Folder level1aab = new Folder(); level1aab.addMessage(new Message());

    //adding children (level1aaa and level1aab) to its parent level1aa
    level1aa.addChildren(level1aaa);
    level1aa.addChildren(level1aab);
```

This what I have. It is not correct, with each new level adedd, if `root` is passed to the function, I get one extra `count` more. But if I pass some node `Folder` from any level between leaf and root, I get correct result. I also tried with the debugger, slowly, writing stack frames like from lectures. But can't seem to wrap my mind around this.

```
public static int numberOfMessages(Folder folder){
    int count = 0;

    count+= folder.getMessages().size();

    for (Folder child : folder.getChildren()) {
        if (child.hasChildren()) {

            count += numberOfMessages(child);
        }
        count += child.getMessages().size();
    }

    return count;
 }
```

From what I figured, it seems when it starts returning calls somehow `level1a's` `Message` get counted two times. I don't know why. I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, just now, I came up with this. If someone can verify or try to suggest me how to improve it.

```
public static int numberOfMessages(Folder folder){
    int count = 0;

    for (Folder child : folder.getChildren()) {
        count += numberOfMessages(child);
    }

    return count + folder.getMessages().size();
 }
```